# Is it possible to copy an entire directory when deploying to Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles

I'm using Azure and need files to be copied from my project to Azure's approot directory.
For this I go to file-->properties-->build action and set
**Build Action:** Content
**Copy to Output Directory:** Copy Always

It works great for files but now I need to upload several directories.
Is it possible to upload an entire directory to Azure's approot?

I'm using .Net 4.5, Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. But as far as I know, you have to edit your `.csproj` manually to do it. Use a `*` or `**` to recurse, like so:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="startup\**">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
```

I usually add a single file manually and then just change the generated line in my `.csproj`.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio UI folder don't have any property setup instead only files have propertied which is used by compiler and other packaging tools. If selecting each file is an issue, you do can select all the files in specific folder using keyboard shortcut (Shift + _top_file & _bottom_file in folder) and then just use property setup once.

Comment: I tried this, however, I have a complex directory structure and cannot change the attribute of multiple files + directories.